# Keyboard shortcut for prev/next sheet in Numbers 3

Tags: keyboard, numbers

Is there a keyboard shortcut for moving to the next or previous sheet in Numbers 3? I have a dream I found those shortcuts, but can't seem to figure out what they were...

Comment: there is some information here http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14849

Comment: Yes, but not the information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been added in Numbers 3.2, released 2014-04-01.  Numbers now honors the ⌘-{ and ⌘-} keystrokes for previous and next sheet, respectively.  Additionally, the menu items are now under the Window menu to be remapped.

Numbers 3.0 and 3.1 did not have this feature.

Comment: Good timing! :)

Answer (score 0):

preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts

There you can find all existing shortcuts. If you do not find it, you can create it by yourself.

Comment: The existing shortcuts are not there, and I cannot add shortcuts for items that are not in the application menus.